# How can I make a link in menu that open a URL in Android studio in adforest classified native android app?

Tags: android, url, android-intent, android-studio-3.4

how can I add in the menu in the android studio a link that opens all ads belong to a specific location (I want to put a specific location in the menu)?

I think I must add some code in the `activity_home_drawer.xml`, but I don't know how!!

In the website, the URL that open ads belong to an specific location is like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/ad_country/india/
```

I just need a link in the menu that opens this URL inside the app.

This is `activity_home_drawer.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/group1"
        android:checkableBehavior="single"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_outline"
            android:title="" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:title="" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_mail_outline_large"
            android:title="" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/packages"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_price_tag"
            android:title="" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/myAds"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_storage_black_24dp"
            android:title="" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/inActiveAds"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_inactive_black_24dp"
            android:title="" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/featureAds"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_feature_black_24dp"
            android:title="" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/favAds"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_border"
            android:title="" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_shop"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_bag"
            android:title="" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_sellers"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_sellers"
            android:title="" />
    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/pages"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/custom"
            android:title="">
            <menu>

            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/other"
        android:title="">
        <menu>
            <group
                android:id="@+id/group2"
                android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_blog"
                    android:checkableBehavior="single"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_blogger_icon"
                    android:title="" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
                    android:checkableBehavior="single"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
                    android:title="" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_log_out"
                    android:checkableBehavior="single"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp"
                    android:title="" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

I did add below code and I got some error ?!

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/ad_country/india/"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_location"
    android:title="india ads" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have id like this format `@+id/ad_country/india/`. Change this to `@+id/ad_country_india` and this should not throw the error.

Comment: I change @+id/ad_country/india/. To -->   @+id/ad_country_india its show the menu but in app when i click on it no thing happen!! and it not work!!

Comment: Glad to know that helped!

Comment: im new in android studio :| , any other help that how to handle it ?!!

Comment: thank a lot. So in my case what code i have to put ?

Comment: In your activity class

Comment: you guide like you want guide your classmate, by the way thanks for your time.{as i siad im new- you are in level "10" i am in level "1", if possible guide like you want guide a level "1".   ;)

Comment: Can someone be easier and more accurately guide me? Of course, if put the code right here, and tell which files exactly needs to change, it's great

Answer (score 0):

call this method in the `onNavigationItemSelected` for the item that you want to open the url

```
private void openUrl(final String url) {
        if (url!= null) {
          Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
         }

    }
```

Comment: ok - than waht code i have to use in activity_home_drawer.xml ?

Comment: you can use normal item